# UITableView's selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: not working after reloadData in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have the following code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

It deselects a table view cell tapped by the user (with animation) after the table view is reloaded. It has worked fine in iOS 7 and earlier, but in iOS 8 the animation isn't shown.

What changes were made in iOS 8 to cause this? And what's the best way to achieve the same effect in iOS 8?

Comment: What effect are you looking for? Do you really need to reload or just update the cell?

Comment: 1. why are you reloading the data when a row is selected?

Comment: I call `reloadData` to update the table (either adding or removing rows, depending on the selection) and show a checkmark next to the selected row. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do what I need (still relatively new at this), but the code worked fine in iOS 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

What is the surrounding code that's causing you to call `[tableView reloadData]`?

Depending on how much processing you are doing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the surrounding methods, this can be an expensive operation.

You can run:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
// Update code here
[tableView endUpdates];
```

without having to reload the entire tableView datasource.

When `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, the cell is already selected. So there shouldn't be any need to call the tableView's `selectRowAtIndexPath` method. Simply calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath` should do the trick after updating your cells

Comment: I call `reloadData` to update the table (either adding or removing rows, depending on the selection) and show a checkmark next to the selected row. I guess it is pretty expensive and I should be doing it differently (I'm still relatively new at this). However, the code worked fine in iOS 7 and earlier.